find keywords in jupyter cells and run (Problem of simultanous runs)
I have successfully made several functions that search inputted keywords (they can be comments, codes, markdowns, or raw codes) inside the current jupyter ipynb file and run any cells containing those keywords. I am satisfied with my work but one problem is that running cells by Javascript command inside a loop will simultaneously run selected cells. This is not a problem  for small processes but I believe that might cause problem for heavy process. Does anyone have any suggestion about how to make these runs sequential and orderly so that each run wait till the previous run is finished? Also if anyone has a better idea about searching and running jupyter cells with keywords I appreciate your suggestion.
My codes contain two jupyter cells (cell A and B) that one produces a jupyter widget to input keywords and functions to: 1) read ipynb file (using ipynbname library, you have to install it by pip install ipynbname), 2) search keywords (kwsearch function), 3) index each jupyter cell by reading ipynb file (cell_indices, the last index in cell_indices corresponds to the current code cell number), and 4) connect keyword indices to the corresponding cell indices (indice_matcher).
Cell B runs cell A functions for any updated value inside text input widget and run resulted cells in a loop. The only reason that cell A and B should be separated is because running cell A will cause the text widget to be updated into the default values (becomes empty), hence another cell should call the modified inputs and functions.
Below compose cell A:
### trying to make Jupyter ipynb to run cells containing especial keywords
# cell A >> preparing functions and the input widget
# kw is short form of keyword(s)

import numpy as np 
import codecs
import ipynbname  #pip install ipynbname
from IPython.display import Javascript, display
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Layout, Textarea



ID = '5oG9gNy7myn/k86/+/8cemphdkEsK237SjQltj2GZGU=' # unique ID for finding current code cell number inside ipynb file


def indice_matcher(j01,j02): # if positive difference of j02[n] and j01[n] is less than j01[n] and j01[+1] then they have matching indices
    '''j01 has the bigger range '''
    jj = []
    for j1 in range(len(j01)-1):
        for j2 in range(len(j02)):
            if j02[j2] - j01[j1] < j01[j1+1] - j01[j1] and j02[j2] - j01[j1] > 0: 
                jj.append(j1)
            
    return jj  # returns list indices of matched indices

def kwsearch(x,char):  # x is the big string and char is the small string
    f = 0
    i = []
    f = x.find(char)
    i.append(f) 
    while f != -1:
        f = x[i[-1]+1:].find(char)
        i.append(f+1+i[-1]) 
    
    return i[:-1] # returns all indices of ONE searched character inside x string

def flat(lis):
    ''' # Converts a nested list into a flat list; 
    source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-a-nested-list-into-a-flat-list/'''
    flatList = []
    # Iterate with outer list
    for element in lis:
        if type(element) is list:
            # Check if type is list than iterate through the sublist
            for item in element:
                flatList.append(item)
        else:
            flatList.append(element)
    return flatList

def kwrun(kw_string):
    kw_string.append(ID)
    N = len(kw_string)
    # nb_fname = ipynbname.name()  # current ipynb file's name
    nb_path = ipynbname.path()  # current ipynb file's path
    f=codecs.open(nb_path, 'r')
    current_ipynb = f.read()    

    kw_indices = [] # indices of all inputted keywords
    for n in range(N): # the loop repeats itself till N keywords are searched
        kw_indices.append(kwsearch(current_ipynb,kw_string[n]))

    cell_indices = kwsearch(current_ipynb,'"cell_type"')   # searching "cell_type" inside ipynb file helps us to find indices for all cells 
    # calculating selected cell number
    cell_n = [] 
    for n in range(N): # the loop repeats till N kewords are searched
        cell_n.append(indice_matcher(cell_indices,kw_indices[n]))  # returns list of cell numbers that should be run ; # cell numbers in this way is equal to cell_indices' number of each index
    cell_n = flat(cell_n)
    print(f'Running Cells: {cell_n[:-1]} \n current code cell number: {cell_n[-1]}')    
    return cell_n

    ## making the text widget
    tw = widgets.Text(description='Keywords')
    
    mylayout = Layout(width='51px', height='30px', border = '2px solid blue')
    
    button1 = widgets.Button(description="Run!", layout=mylayout)
    ### VERY IMPORTANT: the Run button only works if you place Cell B as the second cell in your jupyter-notebook. 
    ### You can change index value [1] to any other cell index value you placed Cell B in but you can't define a variable outside function on_button_clicked
    output = widgets.Output()
    
    # display()
    
    def on_button_clicked(b):
        with output:
            display(Javascript(f'IPython.notebook.execute_cells([1])'))
    
    
    button1.on_click(on_button_clicked)
    
    GridBox(children=[tw, button1],
            layout=Layout(
                grid_template_rows='0px 30px',
                grid_template_columns='300px 0px',
                grid_gap='10px 10px',
                grid_template_areas='''
                "tl tl"
                "tl tl"
                '''
    ))


And below codes represent cell B:
# cell B >> search and run
cell_n = kwrun((w1.value).split()) # tw.value is value of inputted words inside cell 1 widget; the keywords should be separated by space
for n in range(len(cell_n)-1): # the -1 in range removes loops to run current code cell number (cell A)
    display(Javascript(f'IPython.notebook.execute_cells([{str(cell_n[n])}])')) #if a name is not found, no cell will be run

After running cell A once to produce the widget, by inputting any desired keyword, run cell B (or just click on Run button of cell A, if you positioned cell B to a correct cell index defined in on_button_clicked function of cell A). By that, cells that contain inputted keywords will be run, but what might become a problem later is that they run simultaneously.
Some final considerations: if you use above codes, choose long unique unspaced strings for desired cells. If keywords are repeated in different cells, all those cells will be run simultaneously.
These functions help to run necessary jupyter cells at the beginning of each work by remembering the most crucial keyword in each cell. for example I use "#.NPY" keyword to load the cell that loads my original dataset like below:

Thank you.
